# Create a new macro for listing rockcandy

Tags: extensions, module-display

I tried this for couple of hours,but i cant find the solution, I'm using the rock candy for short code. And i tried to create listing

```
[list class="{class}"][li]{text}[/li][/list]
```

And html

```
<ul class="{class}"]<li>{text}</li>[/ul>
```

it's show only one list in output and if the list have more then once its not show and output like

```
[list class="bullet-1"][li]listing1[/li][li]listing2[/li][li]listing3[/li][/list]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two macros. Only then you can repeat `[li][/li]`, otherwise it won't match with macro.

**First**

---

For `<ul>`

Macro:

```
[list class="{class}"]{content}[/list]
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="{class}">{content}</ul>
```

**Second**

---

And for `<li>`

Macro:

```
[li]{text}[/li]
```

HTML:

```
<li>{text}</li>
```

**Output**

---

Then you can do:

```
[list class="test"][li]test[/li][li]test2[/li][/list]
```

Output:

```
<ul class="test">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```